# Selecting duplicate id's from an SVG exported from Illustrator in d3.js

Tags: jquery, regex, svg, d3.js, adobe-illustrator

I'm currently trying to work with a fairly complex SVG I've created in Illustrator with d3.js. The SVG is a floor plan, with each floor as its own layer. To show one floor, I just need to show that layer, and hide the others, which is very convenient to keep it all in one SVG.

An issue I'm having though, is that when I export from Illustrator, there are some elements with the same name. For example, I have an `Elevator A` element on each floor layer. When I export to an SVG though, it will eliminate duplicate id's by renaming those to something like `id = "elevator_a_1"` and `id = "elevator_a_2"` (but not necessarily in order). I suppose one way I could solve the issue in Illustrator would be to uniquely name every element, but I think it would make a bit of a mess of my organization.

My questions are:

1. Is it a strict rule that no id's can be repeated in an SVG, even if it's within a hierarchy? E.g. `1st_floor->elevator_a`, `2nd_floor->elevator_a` that would never be visible at the same time.
2. Is there a way to select an id in d3 by just the beginning of the id (maybe via a regex or [jquery-like](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/))? E.g. `d3.select("[id^='elevator_a']")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. IDs must not be repeated -- they should be unique, regardless of where they appear.
2. D3's selectors are [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). You can use regular expressions for [attribute names](http://www.thegeekyway.com/css-regex-selector-using-regular-expression-css/), using exactly the syntax in your question.